# Regarding OOP design, why is a cast exception thrown at declaration rather than when attempting to call an invalid method?

Tags: java, oop

I've asked a similar question before on SO, but I never really got my thoughts together. I've been wondering why a cast can't succeed at compile time if not calling a method not defined in the declared type. For example, let's say I want to do something ridiculous in Java like:

```
class MyClass extends Object {...}
MyClass foo = "hello";
MyClass foo2 = "hello again";
System.out.println(foo.equals(foo2));
```

Immediately, we'll get a class cast exception. But the `println` statement in theory should succeed - `foo` and `foo2` both inherit from class `Object` and thus have the `equals` instance method. Besides the fact that the compiler sees a mismatch in types with casting a string to a class not in the string hierarchy, I don't see why this can't work. I can't think of a specific time when this would be useful and it probably never would be, but I'm wondering what the implications of this design are. The one benefit I can see would be immediate detection of possible error, but why does Java have to be  so strict to the point that the cast is prohibited, not just frowned upon?

Comment: This code won't throw any exception, because it won't compile. You don't have any cast in there. This can work in a loosely typed language like JavaScript. But Java is a strongly typed language. It's been designed to catch errors as soon as possible, and as close to the actual problem as possible. Clearly, a String is not a MyClass, so casting it to a MyClass is an error. If the exception was thrown in a completely unrelated piece of code, when you actually try calling a MyClass specific method, the root cause of the problem would be much harder to find.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the answer, yeah I was thinking the root reason for this was to catch errors quickly - I just thought that maybe instead of a compiler error we could get a warning? Usually I associate errors with an inability to do something, not a preventative measure.

Comment: The error is because of inability to compile obviously broken code, a preventative measure to keep you from doing *obviously* stupid things. I recommend you read about **strong typing** vs. **loose typing** and the advantages and disadvantages in both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not throw a `ClassCastException`. Compiler will show an error telling that object of class `String` can not be assign to a variable of class `MyClass`. This assignment is clearly a mistake and there are no reasons not to show it at compile time. This is called static typing and it helps to find errors in code immediately.

`ClassCastException` is thrown at runtime. It has exact the same root causes as this error during compilation - it means you had error in your logic. The difference is in inability for a compiler to detect such error at compilation time. Usually it happens when you process objects of unknown type:

```
Map resultMap = request.getResult();
String personId = (String) resultMap.get("personId"); // ClassCastException, somebody put integer in this field
```

Why these things work as they do? Why not allow do everything and have only runtime exceptions?

Well, you choose language that matches your goals better. Java needs static typing because it needs to provide reliability - usually applications and code bases grow over time, systems have several modules and subsystems, servers run 24/7 and you want to be sure that your system will not crash on the 6th day after update because someone made a mistake assigning string to integer.

Comment: Thanks so much. This might seem like a dumb question but it's part of my original one: why can't we cast anything to anything? Let's say I wanted to cast a string to an integer - why do we consider it a mistake? I could do so and only call methods on their common superclass: object. OOP isn't designed to allow this, I know, but is there anything wrong with doing so? Does it violate some rule of  polymorphism?

Comment: @rb612 If this cast was possible, you could cast Integer object to String object and then call length() or substring() method on integer. This does not make sence and is forbidden. You can cast class to any parent class (like cast Integer to Number or Object), but not any class to any class.

Comment: Good point @AdamSkywalker - so to make sure I completely get this, what happens you do this cast from any class to another class in a dynamically typed language? It should throw a runtime exception, right, not compile-time?

Comment: @rb612 check out what is duck typing. usually it will fail on method call, if it is impossible

Comment: duck typing shows the same downsides to polymorphism and inheritance as I was saying, and how to better it. Thanks so much!

Comment: one more followup question for you if you have time. Now I get why a cast from one class to another not in the hierarchy would fail at compile time in Java. But if there's a situation where you downcast and Java uses late binding to determine the runtime type in a downcast that *could* work (so it passes compilation), but it's an invalid cast, it fails at runtime (`ClassCastException`) Is the reason for runtime type checking being as strict as compile-time checking just solely for what you were saying about reliability, or is there more to it?